# Closed form for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x+1)\sin (3x)}{(x^2 + 6x + 10)^2} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, closed-form, residue-calculus

> Find the closed form for $$\mathcal{I} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x+1)\sin (3x)}{(x^2 + 6x + 10)^2} dx$$

**My attempt**

In order to find the closed form for this integral, what I first thought was using residue integration. First of all, notice two things

- The denominador cancels out when $$(x^2 + 6x + 10)^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x^2 + 6x + 10 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{-6\pm \sqrt{6^2-4\cdot 10}}{2} = -3 \pm i$$ Non of these are in the real axis, and the only one on the upper semiplane is $-3+i$.
- From Euler's identity we notice that $e^{3x} = \cos(3x) + i \sin (3x)$. Therefore we can rewrite the integral as $$\mathcal{I} = \Im \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x+1)e^{3ix}}{(x^2 + 6x + 10)^2} dx \right)$$

Now, from residue theory we know that, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x+1)e^{3ix}}{(x^2 + 6x + 10)^2} dx = 2\pi i Res \left(\frac{(z+1)e^{3iz}}{(z^2 + 6z + 10)^2};z=-3+i\right)$$
The pole $-3+i$ has degree $2$, so
$$ Res \left(\frac{(z+1)e^{3iz}}{(z^2 + 6z + 10)^2}; z=-3+i\right) = \lim_{z \to -3+i} \frac{d}{dz}  \left\lbrace (z-(-3+i))^2\frac{(z+1)e^{3iz}}{(z^2 + 6z + 10)^2}\right\rbrace$$

This is where I get stuck since I can´t make it through the calculations. I think there might be other ways to tackle the problem or the limit, any help is truly appreciated :)

Comment: Don't forget that crucial $e^{3\color{red}
{i}z}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always do due diligence and check the semicircular contour vanishes; sometimes it does not. It does in this case, though.

The limit formula for a residue is correct but often a pain to handle. You've also incorrectly calculated the roots, it should be $-3+\color{red}{1}\cdot i$.

The pole is a double pole, and we can write the integrand as: $$(z-(-3+i))^{-2}\cdot\frac{z+1}{(z+3+i)^2}e^{3iz}$$We need to get the Taylor series of the righthand chunk at $-3+i$. Abbreviate $-3+i$ by $\zeta$. The numerator is $z+1=(z-\zeta)+(i-2)$. The denominator is: $$(z+3+i)^{-2}=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}(z-\zeta)+o(z-\zeta)$$The exponential is: $$e^{3iz}=e^{-3-9i}+3i\cdot e^{-3-9i}(z-\zeta)+o(z-\zeta)$$Multiplying them all together, we identify the first order term of the Taylor series as (see Cauchy product): $$\mathrm{Res}=-\frac{1}{4}\cdot e^{-3-9i}-\frac{i}{4}\cdot(i-2)\cdot e^{-3-9i}-\frac{1}{4}(i-2)\cdot3i\cdot e^{-3-9i}=\frac{e^{-3-9i}}{4}(3+8i)$$Multiplying this by $2\pi i$, we find: $$\frac{\pi\cdot e^{-3}}{2}(3i-8)e^{-9i}$$We can read off the imaginary part as: $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(x+1)\cdot\sin(3x)}{(x^2+6x+10)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2e^3}(3\cos(9)+8\sin(9))\approx0.0440732$$

---

I have numerically confirmed this with the online version of Wolfram, just to double check I haven't erred; amusingly the calculator fails to evaluate this in a nice closed form.

Comment: I'm sorry about the miscalculation of the roots, I'll edit. How did you come up with the idea that Taylor's first term identifies with the residue?? Very clever solving, thank you so much :)

Comment: @IkerUCM You’re welcome. It’s pretty much by *definition* of residue as the $(-1)$th order term in the Laurent series of the whole function. The order two pole subtracts $2$ from the exponent of every term in the Taylor series; $1-2=-1$, so I know the $(1)$th term - the first term - of the Taylor series is the residue. That’s actually how we justify the derivative formula for the residue, it’s just that working with Taylor series is typically easier.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, integrate in real space with the substitution $y=x+3$

\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(x+1)\sin (3x)}{(x^2 + 6x + 10)^2} dx\\
&=\cos9 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{y\sin (3y)}{(y^2 + 1)^2} \overset{ibp}{dx} +2\sin9 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (3y)}{(y^2 + 1)^2} dx
 \\
&=\frac{3\cos9}2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (3y)}{y^2 + 1} dx  -\sin9 \ \frac{d}{da}\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (3y)}{y^2 + a^2} dx \bigg)_{a=1}
\end{align}
Then, utilize $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos (3y)}{y^2 + a^2} dx= \frac\pi {a }e^{-3a}$ to obtain
$$\mathcal{I} =\frac\pi{e^3}\left(\frac32\cos9+ 4\sin 9\right)
$$